# List Item to open in a separate window

Tags: list

I want List item to open in a window with no more information besides the item information (example: no address bar,no menubar, no navigation bar) just the details related to the item should be shown.

How i can achieve this?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to list settings > advanced settings and select the option to open list items in a modal dialog to yes/true.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in SharePoint 2010 you can create a blank master template and assign that to the display form within SharePoint designer.

This link seems to fix the issue using css and may also work on 2013:
http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/blank-master-page